# why this bean is not null

Tags: java, spring

The following code works fine in spring 4, but I am wondering why the getBean(FooService.class) returns an already-loaded bean. I thought the sequence of bean loading is not guaranteed, meaning that it is possible to get a null bean. Is it because the loading target is a class not a String (ie. object) or is it because the FooService bean has a special scope, like prototype? If so, what is the difference between getBean(class) and getBean(object)

```
public abstract class AbstractService implements ApplicationContextAware {
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    protected FooService fooService;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void postConstruct() {
        fooService = applicationContext.getBean(FooServiceImpl.class);
    }
```

Comment: i think that is the sense of spring to not get null objects

Comment: Actually I think your *bean* is **null**, I mean, you use the *applicationContext* to load the specific bean object. With spring you don't need it. You can use *@Autowired* annotation, on the bean parameter, or more better in a class constructor where the bean is a parameter, or in a *set* method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, String is a full rights class, like any you can create  yourself.

The reason you're getting something in fooService, is that the ApplicationContext [getBean method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-) is able to retrieve a managed bean according to the argument you're passing to it.

If it weren't possible to retrieve the bean, you could get some of these exceptions:

> Throws: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException - if no bean of the given type
>   was found NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException - if more than one bean of
>   the given type was found BeansException - if the bean could not be
>   created

Comment: but what if a bean has not been initialized, ie, not loaded into context, and THIS bean is initialized earlier than FooService bean. In this way, getBean would return null.

Comment: is it true, that applicationContext.getBean(...) is just like (at)Autowired, that spring would ensure to return one bean if it could find its definition?

Comment: Actually Autowired is better, in the sense that using an annotation means lower coupling.

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationContext::getBean` method creates the bean of the specified type if it has not been created already.

For the following two bean classes:

```
@Component
public class Bean1 {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Bean1() {
        System.out.println("Bean 1 constructor");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Bean 1 @PostConstruct started");
        applicationContext.getBean(Bean2.class);
        System.out.println("Bean 1 @PostConstruct completed");
    }
}

@Component
public class Bean2 {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Bean2() {
        System.out.println("Bean 2 constructor");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Bean 2 @PostConstruct started");
        applicationContext.getBean(Bean1.class);
        System.out.println("Bean 2 @PostConstruct completed");
    }
}
```

the printed output during context initialization is:

```
Bean 1 constructor
Bean 1 @PostConstruct started
Bean 2 constructor
Bean 2 @PostConstruct started
Bean 2 @PostConstruct completed
Bean 1 @PostConstruct completed
```

As for different `getBean` methods, if you pass in a class, then exactly one bean of that class has to be present in the application context (otherwise Spring would not not which of multiple bean instances of that class you ask for), whereas searching by name allows you to get a specific named bean instance.

Comment: could you find an official doc supports "@PostConstruct method, which is invoked after all of the beans have been created." Based on its comments, postConstruct is invoked right after THIS bean is constructed. And I think, every bean is constructed one after another. So a little more evidence please :)

Comment: @Tiina You seem to be right, there is no guarantee that beans which are not autowired explicitly have been created at this point. I edited my answer.